# Selecting gidNumber for new user on openLDAP does not add user to group

Tags: openldap

I have ou=users and ou=groups under my base dn. Given group A with gidNumber 100, when I create a new posixAccount user using phpldapadmin, gidNumber is a required field with options of group names (eg. "A"). After creating the user object, the gidNumber has changed from "A" to A's corresponding gid, 100, however the member list of A is empty. If gidNumber does not correspond to group membership, what is the point of the attribute?

Comment: After creating the user object how? I don't see how you got as much to happen as you did. OpenLDAP doesn't do any of this automatically.

Comment: I used phpLDAPAdmin. Nothing was done automatically.

Comment: So how did the gidNumber get changed from "A" to A's corresponding GID? And if you aren't asking a proramming question you're off topic here.

Comment: That happens automatically on the phpLDAPAdmin console. And this technically isn't a programming question, but it is causing programming failures.